# MS Access Query - Incompatible Types (Dates)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get a range of records within the last 5 years. Unfortunately, the data type on my column is a string with a slightly odd formatting. For example, December 2018 would be represented as : `2018/012`.

I have tried making the following query :

```
SELECT tbl.StrDate
FROM tbl
WHERE DateValue(StrDate) > DateAdd("yyyy", -5, Date());
```

The query works for a fraction of a second (as in I see the results)... However, it pops up a display saying that there are "*incompatible types within the query criterias*" and the entire column changes to `#Name ?`.

I am not quite sure what is causing this issue. Thanks for the help.

Note: I am using a French version of Access 2010 the wording might be slightly different here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ignoring the invalid "dates":

```
SELECT tbl.StrDate
FROM tbl
WHERE DateValue(IIf(IsDate(StrDate), strDate, Date()) > DateAdd("yyyy", -5, Date())
```

or list - and correct - those "dates":

```
SELECT tbl.StrDate
FROM tbl
WHERE NOT IsDate(StrDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to ignore the day portion, then use `left()` and `val()`:

```
WHERE VAL(LEFT(StrDate, 4)) > DateAdd("yyyy", -5, Date());
```

Actually, `LEFT()` isn't needed, but I prefer to keep it for clarity.